# Multi level interface inherintace issue in C# while cast class obj from mid level interface

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

I hv two entities, USER and Document. both have their own interface Iuser and I Document.

```
 public class UserRepository : IUserRepository<UserRepository>
    {
     public string GetUser()
        {
            return "Akash";
        }
  }

public interface IUserRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
       string GetUser();
    }

 public class DocumentRepository : IDocumentRepository<DocumentRepository>
    {
     public string GetDocument()
        {
            return "Akash";
        }
  }

public interface IDocumentRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
       string GetDocument();
    }
```

Below is the base interface. All repo interfaces implement this base interface. It is empty ( on purpose) as I just want to store all repo class object in this IRepository interface variable.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {

    }
```

and than, in my UOW ( unit of work ) class, I am creating the repo instance as follows,

```
public IRepository<UserRepository> UserProfile
        {
            get
            {
                return GetRepository<UserRepository>();
            }
        }

 private IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            return (IRepository<T>)new T();
         }
```

Now the problem is: repo object does not have the methods implemented in each repo class. It is obvious as I am type casting my repo object with IRepository interface which does not have any methods. I am looking for a work around. my purpose is to store all repo object in IRepository  variable. Kindly suggest. This is typical OOP's issue.

Comment: Instead of `.GetUser()` or `.GetDocument()` make it generic `.Get<T>()`.

Comment: This is an example I have given To simplify my issue. In reality , I have almost 10 such repositories with each repository having it's own methods.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: but I have clearly mentioned that what I am trying to a achieve and what I have attempted to do so. Now looking for a way we can implement what I am trying to achieve. Not sure how it is an xy problem. I mentioned my attempted approach ( which failed) just to keep thinks in perspective.

Comment: If you think, my design has flaw than please point out that as well.